# Flutter web : Do not call didCreateEngineInitializer by hand

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am running my flutter application in the chrome browser and it will show the following error.

```
Do not call didCreateEngineInitializer by hand. Start with loadEntrypoint instead.
TypeError: this._didCreateEngineInitializerResolve is not a function
```

My Flutter `doctor --verbose` output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.1, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.3.1 on channel stable at /Users/urvashikharecha/Desktop/FlutterSDKs/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4f9d92fbbd (7 days ago), 2022-09-06 17:54:53 -0700
    • Engine revision 3efdf03e73
    • Dart version 2.18.0
    • DevTools version 2.15.0
```

[image]

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I had the same issue and finally soved it.. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74242204/typeerror-this-didcreateengineinitializerresolve-is-not-a-function/74242734#74242734

Answer (score 2):

**Hope the problem persist in index.html file. please add the file or content to find out the issue**